# MVC - Routing entry based on url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am new to mvc and I need to create an application to where the user will be using one of 2 urls. One url will direct to a generic registration and the other will direct to a customized user profile update page. (In a website this would be in the  page_load method.) Where would be the correct place to write this logic within the mvc application?

Comment: MVC version? Take a look here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/785710/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-A and
http://www.webdevelopmenthelp.net/2014/03/routing-in-asp-net-mvc.html

Comment: I think you didn't even create the sample mvc application in visual studio because that does exactly this. Please read about and try asp.net mvc.

Comment: I actually did create the sample mvc app. but I was not clear on how this happens. @blacai the links were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In your WhateverController, you have to create 2 methods :

```
public ActionResult GenericRegistration()
```

and

```
public ActionResult ProfilPage(int profilID)
```

So you have 2 urls : /Whatever/GenericRegistration and Whatever/ProfilPage/{id}

Additionally, you can create another ProfilPage method who can accept the POST action from your html form when the user update its data :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProfilPage(MyFormModel formModel)
{
  // update user profile
}
```